# Try to dual boot elementary OS with windows 10

Tags: boot, microsoft-windows

Initial situation: 
 - 1 x 120GB SSD (GPT) Windows partition 
 - 1 x 500GB HDD (GPT) elementary OS partition

As you can read in the title i try to achieve a dual boot setup with elementary OS and windows 10. My Windows is currently installed on sda (SSD) and elementary OS on sdb (HDD). Currently I just can boot into eOS with grub.

I already tried using boot-repair with different parameters. It seems that windows boot partition is kinda fucked up. I also tried to fix that by typing some repair commands in the cmd (bootrec /fixboot...).

For further informations you can look at this http://paste2.org/FDw1P5On

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

I believe that  updates Grub to look for other installed operating systems and add them to its list.

Other than that, there are too many variables as to what can be the problem. This really cannot be fixed over text on the internet. It is a hands on deal.